# How to rename a subfolder in php

Tags: php

I have created a folder using php whenever a new client creates a business name

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO kd_aboutus (business, category, subcategory, content, uafk, datein) VALUES ('$bn','$cat','$scat','$descr','$userID',now())";
    $run_sql = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (!file_exists("user/$bn")) {
        mkdir("user/$bn", 0755);
    }
```

Now my problem is when the user wants to edit his or her business name, I also need to rename their folder which they had already created. How am I supposed to do this. 
This is my code in the edit file

```
$sql = "UPDATE kd_aboutus SET business='$bn', category='$cat', subcategory='$scat', content='$descr' WHERE aboutID='$targetID'";
    $run_sql = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Comment: Not really an answer, but you can use the id *(like the autoincrement id)* of the business when creating a folder instead, so even if the business renames, their id stays the same

Comment: What have you tried so far? What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

You will need the [rename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) function. Note that the minimum parameters are `string $oldname , string $newname`, so you will need to load the current name before changing the record in the database.

## Example

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT business FROM kd_aboutus WHERE aboutID='$targetID'";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    if (!empty($row['business'])) {
        $oldBn = $row['business'];
        rename("user/$oldBn", "user/$bn");

        $sql = "UPDATE kd_aboutus SET business='$bn', category='$cat', subcategory='$scat', content='$descr' WHERE aboutID='$targetID'";
        $run_sql = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    }
}
```

The above is untested but should illustrate the sort of thing you'll need to achieve.

Comment: Glad to hear it :) Note you can accept this answer if you feel it is the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

You will first have to get current folder name before renaming it.

```
SELECT business FROM kd_aboutus WHERE aboutID='$targetID';
```

Get the result of above query in a variable. Let's say `$oldbn`

Then, [rename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) the folder as:

```
rename("user/$oldbn", "user/$bn");

$sql = "UPDATE kd_aboutus SET business='$bn', category='$cat', subcategory='$scat', content='$descr' WHERE aboutID='$targetID'";
$run_sql = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Comment: I get this error "Catchable fatal error:  Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string" whenever I run your code

Comment: Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string

Comment: And it doesn't rename the existing folder.

Comment: There is something wrong in your implementation. Check @LeonardChallis's answer. He has provided complete implementation.

Comment: Checked. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

PHP has function to rename a folder / file: http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

```
rename(oldname,newname[,context])
```

Comment: Yes, thou am not able to crack it. with that function. Would you mind giving an example please as per my edit file?